# when running docker-compose I get: client version 1.38 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.37"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am using docker compose as follows:

```
version: '3.7'
services: 
  couchdb:
    image: "ibmcom/couchdb3:preview"
    container_name: couch-api-test
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
```

and here is my docker version:

```
+ docker version
Client:
 Version:   18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:10:01 2018
 OS/Arch:   linux/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  18.03.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   0520e24
  Built:    Wed Mar 21 23:08:31 2018
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

and my docker-compose version is:

```
docker-compose version 1.25.0, build 0a186604
docker-py version: 4.1.0
CPython version: 3.7.4
```

When I run my docker-compose in my ubuntu 16 server I get this:

```
client version 1.38 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.37", "stderr_lines": ["client version 1.38 is too new. Maximum supported API version is 1.37"
```

Can anyone shed light on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API calls made by the `docker-compose` client are versioned to ensure that clients don't break. For example to create a container it makes a `POST` to:

```
/v1.36/containers/create?name=...
```

The API version used for the calls is based on the `version` directive in the `docker-compose.yml` file. I couldn't find in the documentation the correspondence between the docker-compose file format and the API but I assume for version 3.7 the API version is 1.38.

The 18.03.0-ce docker engine release is compatible with compose file format up to 3.6 and API version 1.37 according to this compatibility matrix:
[Compose file versions and upgrading](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-matrix)

The problem is that the docker-compose client is newer than the engine and it understands the 3.7 format but this format is incompatible with the engine. To make things work use
 `version: '3.6'` or update the engine to version 18.06.0+

Hope this helps.